# Location/GeoLocator/GeoLocation does not return me my latitudinal and longitudinal

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

I have tried all the different packages such as geolocator/location/geolocation but I just couldn't get coordinates of my current location. The longitudinal and latitude seem to fix at Lat: 37.421 and Lon: -122.084. I even tried to run other people's projects like this one. https://github.com/alfanhui/new_geolocation
All of them return the same lat and lon. Anyone experience this before ??

Comment: Is this related to Google Maps?

Comment: yes i am trying to use google map api in my flutter project. The emulator keeps returning my a default lat and lon.

Comment: Are you using [Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro)? Would you be able to provide your sample implementation of this and the request you are sending?

Comment: The for the reply but I have solved the problem already. Apparently the android studio emulator doesn't give me my current GPS location so I just have to built the app on my android phone and the problem is solved. Thx for replying here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using your emulator to work. 
An emulator can only show a fixed data and does not locate your current location as it does not have location services.
To change the fixed location on the emulator, you could go to the three dots on the side panel of the emulator and fix the location to some other place's latitude and longitude.

Now to answer your question, you will probably get your current location if your code is bug free when you launch the same application on an Android phone which has location services.